# How to move caret in <input type="number">?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm trying to get the caret to move when the `input` is clicked. The code I've found works when the `input` type is `text`. But when you set it as `number` - it does not work. Also how would I get it to pass the length without declaring a value (i.e. `55`) in the parameters?

**HTML**

```
<input type="number" name="cost" value="0.00" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
$.fn.setCursorPosition = function (pos) {
    this.each(function (index, elem) {
        if (elem.setSelectionRange) {
            elem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
        } else if (elem.createTextRange) {
            var range = elem.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', pos);
            range.moveStart('character', pos);
            range.select();
        }
    });
    return this;
};

$('input[name=cost]').click(function() {
    $('input[name=cost]').setCursorPosition(55);
});
```

**EDIT:**
Did some digging and found out that chrome does not let you do this with `number`... Does anyone know of a work around that's cross browser and that doesn't require the type to be switched to `text`?

**EDIT 2:**
Well after a lot of searching it looks like there is no workaround to get this to work with type `number`. I don't get it. Why do browser manufactures do this? I swear we should start making all are elements pseud elements just to piss them off. Especially Google, that would cause havoc on there precious little search algorithm

Comment: `input.selectionStart=input.selectionEnd=input.value.length`

Comment: That wasn't very helpful and i ran into a bunch google searches using that method and they don't work with number and they are inconsistent in chrome.

Comment: sorry, i didn't realize chrome didn't like it... what about input[type=number] appeals to you?

Comment: The fact that it validates it's self on forms and also it brings up the number touch-pad on smartphones rather then the full keyboard.

Comment: well, you can use the _pattern_ attrib to validate numbers on text inputs. that mobile aspect is important though. it might be worth modifying the type just for chrome desktop, if you you want the selection more than the inc/dec buttons. you also might not be able to use _pattern_ with a number input, so you would have to toggle that to. there is no other workaround afaik...

Comment: Mostly it's for the mobile aspect in the desktop I've reset all styling to make it look like a regular text field.

Comment: What exactly for do you need to set the caret to a specific position?

Comment: It's supposed to be a currency field so i want it to start typing from right to left while it replaces the 0.00

Comment: @Darkrum is there ever a decimal? You could right align it, give a placeholder of "0" and then position a `span` so that it appears that ".00" is part of the field (but is uneditable).

Answer (score 2):

Try working around it by changing the input's `type` attribute to `text` on keydown, and back to `number` on keyup.

A little hacky, but will solve the problem.

Comment: i believe the caret is lost upon transition back to type number